# StackOverflow site display issue in chrome browser

Tags: support

I am having 2 issues with the SO website running in chrome browser
`(Version no 33.0.1750.146 ).`

First. The questions are displayed like this

[image]

But I want this to be displayed like this ( in firefox browser)

[image]

Second. The notifications like new questions, comment, answer are not working unless page is refreshed.

So please help me in resolving this issue.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have clicked the "mobile" link in the footer and changed themes.

Click the "full site" link to return to the desktop mode.