# Stack Overflow site notifications issue on Chrome

Tags: support, notifications

I have searched but was not able to find a solution to my problem. The notifications like new questions, comments, or answers are not working unless the page is refreshed in Chrome. [Here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/225271/stackoverflow-site-display-issue-in-chrome-browser), [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/119912/im-seeing-a-very-minimalistic-version-of-the-site-how-to-get-the-full-version) and [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/225968/stackoverflow-not-showing-notifications-and-rep-changes-in-chrome) similar questions were asked. But my issue is not solved even after those recommendations.

1. I am using latest Chrome on 2 different PCs with Windows 7 and Windows 8.1. The problem occurs with both of them, but everything is ok in Mozilla.
2. I am using uBlock, but notifications are not working even when uBlock is disabled
3. I was not able to find a "full site" link. Where is it?

Any suggestions?